# Hiding text in a link

Tags: html, css, web

I have a couple of questions about the problem of hiding text inside an anchor tag and only displaying a background image.

Note to those about to bombard me with links to other articles and tell me that this is a repeat question: I have scoured this site and the web in general and read the solutions (and by solutions I mean mostly hacks) people came up with. What most people seem to be doing (or have done up until recently) was the `-9999px` hack. Also popular is/was wrapping the text in a span and doing something like [this](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/) or `visibility: hidden`.

Now, I personally think that "hiding" the text would really only make sense in the first place if it was hidden *dynamically*, i.e. displayed only if the background image wasn't loading (for whatever reason). However, all the "solutions" I found effectively remove the text completely or at least hide it permanently so even if the background image isn't loaded, the text still wouldn't be displayed.

So here are my questions:

1. Why would one want to have text and then permanently hide it at all? Why not just leave the anchor empty - i.e. just don't put any text in it - and only have the image displayed? Why have text and then go through the headache of figuring out how to hide it? What's the point of that? Am I missing something here?
2. Now that we have CSS3, are there actual non-hacky, dynamic ways to hide text when the background image is displayed and have the text appear when the image - for whatever reason - fails to load? I couldn't find any resources so I am assuming this is not supported but maybe one of you ninjas knows better?

Comment: 1. SEO and/or accessibility 2. For that specific use the `alt` attribute has been around about as long as the img tag has existed.

Answer (score 1):

There are different possibilities why to do that:

1. Search Engines scan the web and also gather content that is visually hidden. The site gets better in terms of semantics and has a higher page rank.
2. Many visually impaired people rely on content that's read to them by screenreaders. Sometimes text in the `alt`-tag is just not enough. Background images don't even have such a tag.

To your second question:
To me there is no known way to check if a background-image is successfully loaded and is also shown (a totally different story!). CSS only styles content according to defined rules. There may be a javascript way to do it, but in my opinion it isn't worth the cost because mostly this text isn't really a fallback. It has a different purpose as stated above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Those are sensible reasons to have text and hide it that I absolutely didn't think of.